# Net::SSH gem non_interactive invalid option?

Tags: ruby, ssh

I have Ruby code like so:

```
def make_ssh user, pass
  begin
    Net::SSH.start(@host, user, :password => pass, :non_interactive => true) do |session|
      @ssh = session
      puts @ssh
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e
  end
end
```

In the Net::SSH library [source](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/master/lib/net/ssh.rb%20source)/[repo](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/), the `:non_interactive` command is supposed to negate the password prompt (and I'm assuming use the key/value `:password => pass` for authentication), but everytime I try to run my code, I am getting an "invalid option" error.

I have tried this with and without the ssh block, and also as

```
Net::SSH.start(@host, user, {:password => pass, :non_interactive => true})
```

but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same eror as yours. This option is added in net-ssh 2.10.0. You are probably using the lower version.